# Arraylist of objects checking specific values of an object

Tags: java

```
public class Library{
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList = new  ArrayList<Book>();
    public ArrayList<Book> viewBooksByAuthor(String author ){
        ArrayList<Book> b =new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book bl:bookList){
            if(bl.getAuthor().equals(author)){
                b.add(bl);
            }
            return b;
        }
        return b;
    }


}
```

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
                        System.out.println("Enter the author name:");
                        String auth=sc.next();
                        ArrayList<Book> ba=l.viewBooksByAuthor(auth);
                        if(ba.isEmpty()){
                            System.out.println("None of the book published by the author "+auth);
                        }
                        else{
                            for(Book an:ba){
                            System.out.println("ISBN no: "+an.getIsbnno());
                            System.out.println("Book name: "+an.getBookName());
                            System.out.println("Author name: "+an.getAuthor());
                            }
                        }

    }
```

I have two classes Book.java and Library.java i want to implement the viewAllBooks() method in which i am passing the author name as an argument and the method will return an ArrayList which will contain all the books with that author name but i am not getting the proper output if i add 2 books with same author then after searching for author name i only get one book details how can i fix that?

Comment: Have you implemented *any* of what you are asking about?

Comment: Show what you have tried, and any error messages/unexpected behaviours you encounter

Comment: @ScottHunter I implemented that method but i am not getting proper output can you please help?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewBooksByAuthor` there is a return statement inside the for loop which will exit your function immediately after the first iteration. Drop the inner return statement (but keep the outer) may solve your problem.